# Views are rewritten when I save

Tags: mysql, view

When I save a view on MySQL, it is "rewritten". How I can avoid this?

Example, when saving this view:

```
SELECT * FROM `contas_users`
```

It is rewritten to:

```
select `contas_users`.`id` AS `id`,`contas_users`.`username` AS 
`username`,`contas_users`.`password` AS `password` from `contas_users`
```

I want to avoid this behavior (can be locally only), because I need do some tests, and copy/past to a TXT is too slow and boring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for that, but works only in specific configurations. Here works fine.
The original SOURCE is stored on a file .frm of VIEW. See code below:

```
SELECT LOAD_FILE(CONCAT(@@GLOBAL.datadir, 'tablename/viewname.frm'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should *not* care what mysql does with your query internally.

You *should* be managing your SQL source is some form of source control, but even if you aren't, you should work with your SQL source (text) files *only*, then execute them as a script to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid it. It is MySQL behavior.